# connection String and Listener

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2017, I will like to know how Connection String can be use to talk via Listener to Databases rather talking directly to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Availability Group Listener has a DNS name, for example `AG-Listener-01.domain.com`

In the connection string, you just specify

```
Server=AG-Listener-01,1433;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;User ID=SQLLogin;Password=SQLPassword;
MultiSubnetFailover=True
```